# Не стартует Activity на устройствах Xiaomi, Huawei (Android 8)

Tags: android

В приложении имеется 2 Activity: Splash и Main.  При запуске приложения Splash после загрузки перенаправляет пользователя на Main. Проблема заключается в том, что на устройствах Xiaomi, Huawei, при открытии приложения пользователь снова возвращается на рабочий стол. Визуально происходит вылет приложения.

SplashActivity

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle("Выход")
                .setMessage("Вы хотите выйти?")
                .setPositiveButton("Да", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Нет", null).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);

        WebView mWebView = new WebView(this);

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new AlphabetClient());

        setContentView(mWebView);

        mWebView.getSettings().setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.NORMAL);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/4.html");
    }

    final Activity activity = this;

    public class AlphabetClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().length() == 0) {
                return false;
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
            CookieManager flush;
        }

        String NetError = "<html><body style='background: #000; color: #fff; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 40%;'>" +
                "<center>Упс, ошибочка :(</center>" +
                "</body></html>";

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            view.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, NetError, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
        }
    }
}
```

Манифест

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.romanvht.alphabetOff">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Ну а в лог что то пишет?

Comment: Жалобы пришли от пользователей. Я бы рад просмотреть логи, но под рукой нет подобного устройства. На чистом Android данной версии, всё без проблем работает.

Comment: Посмотрите краши в гугл консоли